# Do 5V high power heater elements exist?

Tags: heat

I am attempting to regulate the temperature inside a not so small (maybe 0.5m^3) box above the ambient. Currently the design is using a bathroom heater spare parts heating element. 230VAC are passed via a triac.

Because the box needs to be opened sometimes, I would like to avoid the risk of electric shock. Furthermore, the design is already using a computer PSU, so 5VDC supply is abundant.

Can I get a combination of heating element and control element (mosfet?), which runs at 5V? The power needs to be at the very least 200W and the price not much higher than 10BGN.

Comment: 200W @ 5V is 40A. That's a lot of really heavy wire!

Comment: @ConnorWolf, I didn't even think about that. And the 12V rail provides much less current capability. Seems the answer to my question would be "no".

Comment: Well, the answer is "Yes", but it's going to be non-trivial. You can buy a [really big](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TGHLVR100JE/TGHLVR100JE-ND/1124815) 0.1Ω resistor, which would *probably* work, but do you have a 40A power supply and the <10 gauge cabling for it?

Comment: @ConnorWolf, the PSU will manage. A 6mm^2 cable for home electrical network should work. What kind of valve element am I going to need if I go this way?

Comment: Are you thinking of using PWM on the heater at 40A????

Comment: If you decide to go with a PC PSU, be sure to test in reality that it can supply high/max load on one rail (i.e. 5V, or 12V) while other rails are lightly loaded - some can't, and it's not always obvious from specs.

Comment: I would go further than @Techydude: most PC PSUs are not designed to supply all of their output as one voltage, and will not cope with this while maintaining good regulation. Furthermore, the majority of the power is expected to be supplied on the 12 V rail, not 5 V. The answer by Bruce Abbott is a good solution.

Comment: Car headlamps make a good (cheap) 12v heater element (55/100W), possibly Moped headlamps will be 6v, close enough to 5v to work. BUT I would just try to make the enclosure so that the heater element can't be touched when it's live (opening the lid cuts the power to it maybe) and stick with 230v as it's going to be much easier.

Comment: Maybe consider a 'brick' 24V/10A supply rather than a PC supply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good PC power supply should be able to deliver 200W, but you may have to balance the load by drawing some current off 5V and some off 12V. You can control it with two MOSFETs, like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4Cgr4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>